# How to rewrite an Nginx GET request into POST?

Tags: nginx, postgrest

My use case is that I have an email containing a "verify your email address" link. When the user clicks this link, the user agent performs a GET request like:

```
GET http://widgetwerkz.example.com/confirm_email?challenge=LSXGMRUQMEBO
```

The server will perform this operation as a POST (because it is a side-effecting operation). I do not have access to the server code at all. The destination request should be:

```
POST http://widgetwerkz.example.com/rpc/verify

{ "challenge": "LSXGMRUQMEBO" }
```

What Nginx rewrite can I perform to achieve this?

*Edit*: solution in context

```
http {
    server {
        # ... 
        location /confirm_email {
            set $temp $arg_challenge;
            proxy_method POST;
            proxy_set_body '{ "challenge": "$temp" }';
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/rpc/verify;
            set $args '';
        }
    }
}
```

This does all these together:

- Converts the request from GET to POST
- Rewrites the location from `/confirm_email` to `/rpc/verify`
- Removes the query string from the request (e.g. resulting url is simply `/rpc/verify`, without the `?challenge=LSXGMRUQMEBO`)
- Adds a JSON body of: `{ "challenge": "LSXGMRUQMEBO" }`

Thanks to Ivan for putting me on the right track!

Comment: Does your nginx acts as a reverse-proxy server to your backend?

Comment: Yes, Nginx is a local reverse proxy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
location /confirm_email {
    proxy_method POST;
    proxy_set_body '{ "challenge": "$arg_challenge" }';
    # your proxy_set_headers and other parameters here
    proxy_pass <your_backend>/rpc/verify?;
}
```

Comment: This _almost_ works, but the query parameter is still part of the request:

`POST http://widgetwerkz.example.com/rpc/verify?challenge= LSXGMRUQMEBO`

and that is causing problems for the backend.

Comment: Try to add a question sign after `/rpc/verify`, this might help. If not, write a comment, I'll search another way to get rid of it.

Comment: That did it, Thanks!